# Make an array/ animation node with adjustable angle and size for instances

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes

I struggle with something might be a simple question. I was trying to make an adjustable array. The array element align the curve that need some loose part and tihgt part for further modifier. And the element I want it to be adjustable can change the angle and change the size.

also the array I'll need to attach it on the surface.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the question not so simple as it looks like. I think the perfect solution for this - [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)

For example, this is a basic setup of objects on curve:

[image]

After this, you can try to find a way how add to control of scale and rotation of objects. For example, I use distance between empty and object to set scale for elements of array:

[image]

[image]

I'm afraid, Animation Nodes is a big topic, that I can't discus in one little post. But I give you an idea and providing file for you:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To control the looseness and tightness of the array of objects based on that of the spline, you can use the **Resolution** option while evaluating the samples. This option is explained in details in the [Documentation](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/get_spline_samples.html#options), so a possible node tree to create the effect you are after is:

[image: Node Tree]